# inotifywait not detecting changed file via Dropbox upload

Tags: dropbox

First question (please be gentle!)...

Extract from a bash script running on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
DB_FOLDER="/path_to_dropbox_folder"
PL="playlist_file"
while true; do
    vlc "${DB_FOLDER}"/"${PL}" &
    VLC_PID=$(pidof vlc)
    ### Watch for changes to the selected playlist file
    inotifywait -qq -e modify "${DB_FOLDER}"/"${PL}"
    kill -9 $VLC_PID
done
```

If I edit/save, or simply overwrite $PL with another playlist file, inotifywait detects the change, vlc is killed, and reloaded. However, editing/saving the file on a remote (Dropbox-linked) 'puter, whilst resulting in an updated $PL on the 'host machine', does not trigger the inotifywait event. I can see that the file modtime has changed... Baffled.

Edit: Have also tried `-e close_write` and `-e attrib` (no difference). And `-e access` (millions of detections!).

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Never did solve the problem, using inotifywait. Saw the same behaviour on another machine (albeit, also Ubuntu 16.04...).
Achieved what I required using the stat command in a while loop (see VDR's answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes)).

Jon